# Apache/PHP response time and execution time

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a web server application with Apache, PHP and MySQL in Windows Server 2008. The server also serves web pages and images.

Recently I have noticed that some users (8 users out of 150) that upload images have a response time from Apache of 200 seconds for example, but the execution time of the PHP script is 2 seconds. But other users are not affected and they're using the same script.

I know this times because I'm logging each request in a MySQL table.

To obtain the apache response time before the execution ends I use

```
microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]
```

And to obtain the PHP execution time I use

```
microtime(true) - $GLOBALS["tiempo_inicio_ejecucion"];
```

where $GLOBALS["tiempo_inicio_ejecucion"] is another microtime that I get at the beginning of the script execution.

The server load is low, CPU and RAM are far of their limits.

If I try to reproduce this behaviour uploading files from my PC, I can't reproduce it, it uploads fast.

I suppose is some network issue, but I can't get it solved, or maybe is a network issue of the clients.

How can I know what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Files that are being uploaded are not more than 2MB of size.

Comment: what kind of tests have you run so far in trying to reproduce the experience? and what were the results? are you able to provide any of the code involved in the upload?

Comment: I'm testing it using the application like the users, uploading files. The code is complex and in many files but the issue is that before the code begin to execute, a lot of time was spent uploading or something that is not executing the code.

Comment: And this is an issue that appeared yesterday, and the last months work perfectly, and nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried things like uploading with a low speed connection? Or done any benchmarking to test your execution times when there are a number of concurrent connections? Are you hosted on shared hosting? Have you asked your host? Do you know who had the issue, and if so can you reach out and discus it with them?

Comment: I don't benchmarked the script yet. I'm in a cloud server. I asked them and they said me that the network bandwidth is OK, about 2mbps, and the limit is 125 mbps.
I have talked with one client who is experiencing this issue, and he said me that is totally random when it occurs or not. He tested the connection speed in his PC and except one time that was 0,25 mbps of upload, all the times was about 20 mbps or more.

Answer (score 0):

Possible suggestion: A virus checker.

Your server may have a virus checker installed which scans files automatically when they are created. This will be scanning uploaded file. It is possible that it may be running low on resource or being given a low priority by the server, and thus scans of the uploaded files are taking a long time. However it won't release the file to the web server until the scan is complete, and thus the server takes a long time to start running the PHP code.

I have no idea if this is actually your problem, but I have seen similar problems on other Windows Server boxes. It can be a very difficult problem to diagnose.

Comment: I think about that. But there are users uploading files that are not affected by this, so that's not possible the anti virus thing, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it can be something like this even if it's inconsistent. It may kick in only for certain files, or it may be on a timer and some uploads just happen to clash with the time it's doing a scan (eg maybe it locks the uploads folder while it scans it). There's lots of ways a background task like that can affect server performance, and virus checkers are particularly bad at it.

Comment: I've checked all the proccesses in the performance monitor and there's nothing like that. Only httpd, mysql, Windows and network proccesses.